# Need to do a many comments belong to one article relation MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose/MongoDB and I am trying to associate many comments to one article. My app begins by scraping from a website and then the user has the option to save each article that was scraped into the MongoDB. When the user chooses to save one article, I save it into database. So when a user clicks on one of their saved articles, they can comment on them. Each article has its own comment section I need to retrieve the correct comments.

//My post comment request in JS file

```
function postComment(){

    var articleComment = {
        comment: $('#comment').val().trim()
    }

    $.post('/comments/' + articleID, articleComment).done(function(data){
        $('.main-popup').fadeOut();
        console.log('DONNE', data);
    });
}
```

//Post route in controller

```
router.post('/comments/:id', function(req, res){

    var newComment = new Comment(req.body);

    newComment.save(function(err, doc){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            Comment.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": doc._id }, { "article": req.params.id }).exec(function(err, doc){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(err);
                }else{
                    res.send(doc);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

//Get request to get correct comments when clicked on specific article

```
function showCommentBox(){

    $('.comments').empty();
    $('#comment').val("");
    articleID = $(this).attr('data-article-id');

    $.get('/comments/' + articleID, function(data){


        if(data.article){ //This is undefined*********************
            for(var x = 0; x < data.comment.length; x++){

                $('.comments').append("<div><h2>" + data.comment[x].comment + "</h2><span><button>&times;</button></span></div>");
            }
        }
        $('.main-popup').fadeIn();
    });


}
```

//Get route in controller

```
router.get('/comments/:id', function(req, res){
    Comment.findOne({ "article": req.params.id }).populate("article").exec(function(err, doc){

        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            res.json(doc);
        }
    }); 
});
```

//Article Model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var ArticleSchema = new Schema({

    title: {
        type: String
    },
    link: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    img: {
        type: String
    }
});

var Article = mongoose.model("Article", ArticleSchema);

module.exports = Article;
```

//Comment Model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CommentSchema = new Schema({

    comment: {
        type: String
    },
    article: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Article'
    }

});


var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
module.exports = Comment;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing $set when you do .findOneAndUpdate. Also I think you should convert a string to Mongo ObjectId before setting it.
So it might look likt this:

```js
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

Comment.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": doc._id }, {$set: {"article": new ObjectId(req.params.id) }})
```

Also you don't need to make 2 database calls. You could article id before saving newComment and then simply send it as a response like this:

```js
//Please notice that mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId and mongoose.Types.Object are different types.
//You need this one here:
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

router.post('/comments/:id', function(req, res){
 var newComment = new Comment(req.body);
 newComment.article = new ObjectId(req.params.id);

 newComment.save(function(err, doc){
  if (err) {
   console.error(err);
   res.send(err);

   return;
  }

  res.send(doc);
 });
});
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for the input. However, I think I need two calls to the database. When the user clicks on the comments button, that makes my comments modal to show up. The submit button inside my comment modal is what makes the post request.

Comment: @ANonymous I've been talking about different thing. You make 2 calls instead of 1 inside your POST endpoint. 1) .save goest to mongo 2) .findOneInUpdate goest to mongo and modifies the same document. This should be done in one call.